# How to include external javascript in angular template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, braintree

I have a page called index.html with a form that relies on an external javascript:

```
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>
<script>
var clientToken = removed
braintree.setup(
          // Replace this with a client token from your server
          clientToken,
          "dropin", {
            container: "payment-form",
            form: "checkout",
          });
</script>
```

Before integrating this page with angular, I tested to see that it works, but now that I have integrated this page as an angular state: $stateProvider

```
 .state('billing', {
        url: '/billing',
        views: {
            'main': {
                controller: 'BillingController as billingCtrl',
                templateUrl: '/billing/index.html'
            }
        }
    });
```

I receive these errors when routing to said page:

[image]

I would like to avoid relying on 3rd party libraries like braintree-angular. It seems to me that angular template does not recognize  tags since they are used to bind the controllers to the html.

Comment: Have you tried using the 'onEnter' callback to dynamically create the script tag to the 3rd party lib? https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#onenter-and-onexit-callbacks

Comment: just attach to the $window e.g. $window.braintree.setup....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an index.html being generated in the build process that includes all the assets including js/controller files. The answer to include external js file was just to insert my script tag into the index.html file that includes all the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to include a js file is to add its path to the scripts key ( Array of strings) in Angular.js:

1. create a folder inside the assets folder called scripts (for a better structure)
2. add you scripts file into this folder
3. Open angular.json file that exists in the root of the angular project
4. add the path to your file to the scripts key

```html
{
  "projects": {
    "you-will-find-your-project-name-here": {
      "architect": 
            "scripts": ["src/assets/scripts/myScriptsFile.js,]
          },
          ....
}
```